# Disabled all the records book button in gridview1 whose name column values is sumit?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

[image]

I have TextBox1 whose Default text is Sumit and a gridview with records and button field in each row ..

On Page load event

I want if textbox1 text is Sumit .... then all the records in gridview1 whose name column values is sumit .... then that rows Book button will be disabled and rest of all will be remain as it is in Enableed form ...

i m using Visual Studio 2008 with vb

Is this coding is right : ?

```
Protected Sub GridView1_DataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles GridView1.DataBound
        For Each myRow As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows
            'Find the checkbox
            Dim lab1 As Label = DirectCast(myRow.FindControl("Label1"), Label)
            If lab1.Text = "Sumit" Then
                'Find the Delete linkbutton and hide it
                Dim deleteButton As Button = DirectCast(myRow.FindControl("Button1"), Button)
                deleteButton.Enabled = False
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
```

But this coding doesn't disabled the button .... in rows whose name field is Sumit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the grid view item data bound eventhandler, set button.Enabled = false if "name" in the dataitem is sumit.

Comment: Sir, can u provide me the coding for that, i m the beginner

Comment: I would love to. However, I don't know VB.NET. I can give you a C# example, but given that you are a beginner, that probably won't do you much good. Would you like one anyway?

Comment: How to set this :

 if "name" in the dataitem is sumit.

Comment: Perhaps we can arrange to chat about this. We both need to ask a lot of questions and we're just sort of polluting the question.

Comment: How to set this : if "name" in the dataitem is sumit.>> I assume you are binding a DataTable or a list of objects containing the data. If you have declared the data in the markup, then I'm pretty sure your eventhandler won't be called.

Comment: I hope I helped you in the right direction.. Thanks for the answer mark by the way :)